# Android - Show first ten entries in my sql database

Tags: android, mysql, sql, cursor

I want to show only the first ten records in my SQL database. At the moment, my code is as follows:

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        result = result + c.getString(iRow) +  " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScore) + "\n";

    }
```

So, this currently shows all entries into the database as !c.isAfterLast(); is stated. I couldn't see how to specify which position you want to count to as they were getters and not simply querying where the cursor is pointing.

Any help would be appreiated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sqlite LIMIT keyword, for example:

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10

or

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 10
```

I hope it helps.